# Sequential output and input of strings in Go

Tags: go

There is a program that reads two inputs from command line: username and password. The string "Password: " should be printed in console only after entering the username, but in my program it prints right away along with the first string "Username: ". How to fix this?

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "os"
    "fmt"
)
// A simple program that verifies the user by username and password.

var loginstatus bool
var username, password string
func login(username, password string) bool {
    if username == "user123" && password == "pass123" {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}

func main() {
    fmt.Print("Username: ")
    user := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
    fmt.Print("Password: ")
    pass := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)


    for user.Scan() && pass.Scan() {
        if login(user.Text(), pass.Text()) {
            fmt.Println("Signed in.")
            os.Exit(3)
        } else {
            fmt.Println("Incorrect username or password, please try again:")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The line `bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)` just creates a new scanner for stdin it does not actually do the scanning and will not block waiting for user input. It will not actually read from stdin until you call `Scan` by which point "Username:" and "Password:" have already been printed.

You probably don't need two scanners for username and password. One scanner should be enough and you probably want to move the printing of "Username:" and "Password:" into the for loop if you want to be able to try again so it would look something like:

```
func main() {
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)

    for {
        fmt.Print("Username: ")
        if !scanner.Scan() {
            break
        }
        user := scanner.Text()
        fmt.Print("Password: ")
        if !scanner.Scan() {
            break
        }
        pass := scanner.Text()
        if login(user, pass) {
            fmt.Println("Signed in.")
            os.Exit(3)
        } else {
            fmt.Println("Incorrect username or password, please try again:")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare first a new Scanner from bufio.NewScanner and then use the method ReadString to read the data from os.Stdin :

```
func main() {
    scanner := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)

    fmt.Print("Username: ")
    user, _ := scanner.ReadString('\n')
    fmt.Print("Password: ")
    pass, _ := scanner.ReadString('\n')

    if login(user, pass) {
        fmt.Println("Signed in.")
        os.Exit(3)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Incorrect username or password, please try again:")
    }
}
```

Comment: You say you need to read the strings from bufio.NewScanner (which just creates a scanner, it doesn't read any strings, so that's a little misleading), and then your example doesn't use a Scanner at all. This answer could be confusing to newer Go users.

Comment: @Adrian, I've updated the description and code, let me know if it's better now.